# does java tomcat process data in a form of "first come first serve" or parallelly?

Tags: java, tomcat

Ok, I have just realized this issue.

Let say you use Java + Tomcat to build ur web App.

The Tomcat receives 2 call from 2 clients at the same time. The 1st call (will call a series of methods & return an integer) is received by the server before the 2nd.

Call1:

```
String passwordProvidedByUser=action.getPasswordFromClient();
String passwordFromDB=data.getPasswordFromDB();
if (passwordFromDB.equals(passwordProvidedByUser)){
      boolean updated=data.updateInfo();
}
```

Call 2:

```
 String newPassword=action.getPasswordFromClient();
boolean changePwd=data.changePwd(newPassword);
```

So, if Call1 finished `String passwordFromDB=data.getPasswordFromDB();` but has not run the `boolean updated=data.updateInfo();` while call 2 already ran `boolean changePwd=data.changePwd(newPassword);`. That means call 1 `boolean updated=data.updateInfo();` with old password?

My question is that will Tomcat server/Java finish all the actions of 1st call & return the result to the 1st call before it starts to process the 2nd?

Or the Tomcat server/Java just starts to process the 2nd while it is still processing the 1st (ie the server hasn't return a result to the 1st, but already started to process the 2nd)?

Comment: `ur`? What is this... myspace?

Comment: 1) Use case you provided is never to be implemented. 2) If it would, than yah, optimistic locking. All in all, it is not a common practice to provide serial but still concurrent reqeust handling. You are trying to achieve something that probably nobody else would have to. As for optimistic locking in banking system - OFC. This is the common way of processing concurrent modifications of single entity. If you really still see the problem, you will have to invent your own standard for distributed applications, as Java EE, ASP.NET nor more common PHP solutions will be suited for you. IMHO ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call goes on queue from where it is picked up by workers threads for processing - yes, there is pool of threads that are responsible for processing requests so the order of request handling is rather undetermined.

Comment: so It uses "first come first serve"? otherwise we have serious programming issue

Comment: Well requests would be picked from the queue one by one thats for sure, but as for concurrent environement, you cannot guarantee order of response generations. EDIT: OK you CAN guarantee execution order, but it is not by default

Comment: yes, that is what I mean cos if the server has not returned the result to the 1st call & start to process the 2nd then we have a serious programming problem.

Comment: I don't understand where you see the problem here:)

Comment: ok,  say many people can modify the password, ur 1st call will read the session & got the password & it will check with the user pass if matching it will allow u to get data. Now, the 2nd call will change password, so if the 2nd change the password at the time the 1st already got the old password then user can access data with old password??

Comment: This is not as easy as you think it is - we would use entity versioning and optimistic lockig for that. I have another scenerio. Lets say that 1 million ppl logs into facebook, and everyone has to wait for previous user to login before you do. Well that would be an issue.

Comment: "we would use entity versioning and optimistic lockig for that."? does the bank app use this?

Comment: i knew optimistic locking, but my question is more complicated than that. AS  stated in the above ex, even u already use optimistic locking but say ur request involve 2 methods: get data & update that, what if people modify data at the time u finish the 1st method? then even u use op locking u still messing thing up

Comment: Antoniossss, I have just modief my question, if u can look into the ex then u can understand what i mean